# Calculate total value of a key in 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of fruit as in the below code.  I then have 3 arrays with a dictionary inside which gives a value based on position that the fruit has been positioned in array.  I plan to do this within a TableView.  For instance, a fruit in

[0] element would give a value of 4 (fruitName.count)

[1] element would give a value of 3 (fruitName.count - 1) etc...

My problem is that I need to calculate the total amount of fruit from all the arrays for the specific piece of fruit.

```
    var fruitName = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Orange"]
var Group1 = ["Apple": (fruitName.count), "Pear": (fruitName.count-1),"Banana": (fruitName.count - 2), "Orange": (fruitName.count - 3)]
var Group2 = ["Apple": (fruitName.count), "Orange": (fruitName.count - 1), "Pear": (fruitName.count - 2), "Bananna": (fruitName.count - 3)]
var Group3 = ["Pear": (fruitName.count), "Apple": (fruitName.count - 1), "Orange": (fruitName.count - 2), "Bananna": (fruitName.count - 3)]
```

So the result should provide the answer  below.  How would I go about solving this?  I appreciate that the code isn't written perfectly.  I hope I've explained myself ok... Thanks

Apple  -  4 (Group1)  +  4 (Group2) + 3 (Group3) = 11

Pear - 3 (Group1) + 2 (Group2) + 4 (Group3) = 9

Banana - 2 (Group1) + 1 (Group2) + 1 (Group3) = 4

Orange - 1 (Group1) + 3 (Group2) + 2 (Group3) = 6

Comment: This sounds very odd. What is it you are actually trying to do with the day? What is the reason you are using fruitName.count? It seems like you are trying to solve some other problem. On a higher level, what is it you are trying to do with this data?

Comment: Hi Fogmeister,

Yeah this isn't the best explanation.  I've been programming now for 4/5weeks and I'm trying my best to learn.
Ultimately I want to calculate a percentage to see which fruit a user prefers.  As I will have multiple people choosing I want to create an overall average.
So if I take an array of fruitName.count (4 fruits). I can create an index x which can change the element position and reduce the fruitName.count by 1/2/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary value is accessed by its key, so we can run through each fruit in the array, use it as the key to access the count in each array, then add them all together. Note changing the array names to a lowercase "g."

**Edit**
From the comments, the nil coalescing operator is used in case the fruit is not even in the array. Then, the count will be set to 0.

```
for fruit in fruitName {
    let count1 = group1[fruit] ?? 0, count2 = group2[fruit] ?? 0, count3 = group3[fruit] ?? 0
    let fruitTotal = count1 + count2 + count3
    print(fruitTotal)
}
```

Prints

> 11
>
> 9
>
> 4
>
> 6

Comment: 1- What about if you combine the statements like this: `let count1 = group1[fruit], let count2 ...`. 
2- And what if a group doesn't contain that fruit (i.e. `let count1 = group1[fruit] ?? 0`), otherwise it won't print.

Comment: Though this answer cannot be generalized as it is, I like it more than my own answer (for this case), since it's less convoluted (i.e. no `flatMap`'s and alikes) and it's probably more efficient (just a single `for` loop).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have a couple of *Banan**n**a*s in the arrays...
Second of all, all your *variables* are constants (`let`)

Create an array from the groups

```
let groups = [Group1, Group2, Group3]
```

Then iterate thru the `fruitName` array, (flat)map the corresponding values to an array and add the values (`reduce:combine:`)

```
for name in fruitName {
  let max = groups.flatMap({$0[name]}).reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
  print(name + " = \(max)")
}
```

In **Swift 3** the `flatMap` / `reduce` line is

```
let max = groups.flatMap({$0[name]}).reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
```

Comment: One day I will remember all of the elegant nuances of the language. Today is not that day. Nice answer. . . Btw, Xcode says reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1}) has been changed to reduce(0, {$0 + $1})

Comment: Note you can simply pass `+` to `reduce`, rather than `{$0 + $1}` :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not like I don't like the previous answers by @vadian and @Shades, but here it's another way:

```
var x = [String:Int]()
[Group1, Group2, Group3].flatMap({$0}).forEach({ x[$0.0] = $0.1 + (x[$0.0] ?? 0) })
```

And then print them:

```
for (k,v) in x.enumerate() {
  print ("\(k) : \(v)")
}
```